# How to collapse array?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
0 => array:8 [▼
      "_id" => MongoId {#266 ▶}
      "name" => "New param"
      "default" => "900"
      "visibility" => "1"
      "type" => 1
      "only_numbers" => "1"
      "value" => "900"
      "available" => "1"
    ]
```

How to collapse this array into:

```
$arr["New param"] = "900";
```

Only as:

```
$arr = array(
   $a["name"] => $a["value"]
);
```

Comment: You gave yourself an answer. So what shall we do?

Comment: Maybe you can recommend function or more elegant solution

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your array is an element of another array (that's what `0 =>` at the top implies). So you need to index that containing array:

```
$arr[$a[0]['name']] = $a[0]['value'];
```

If you want to get all the elements of that other array, use a loop:

```
foreach ($a as $el) {
    $arr[$el['name']] = $el['value'];
}
```

or you could do:

```
$arr = array_combine(array_column($a, 'name'), array_column($a, 'value'));
```